Multiple /swap-instructions in a transaction / Solana - Jupiter
Hello dear friend i'm trying to send multiple instruction in one TX
So with the jupiter Api i call 2 quotes with /swap-instruction like this :
    Promise.all([
  await fetch("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap-instructions", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      quoteResponse: inQuote,
      userPublicKey: keypair.publicKey.toBase58(),
    }),
  }),
  await fetch("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap-instructions", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      quoteResponse: outQuote,
      userPublicKey: keypair.publicKey.toBase58(),
    }),
  }),
]).then(async ([inQuote, outQuote]) => {
  // .json the responses and get the instructions
  Promise.all([inQuote.json(), outQuote.json()]).then(
    async ([inQuote, outQuote]) => {
      // console.log(inQuote);
      // console.log(outQuote);
    })

But i don't know how to post it please if someone can show me an example ?

I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic. Ethereum Q&A website is not a proper medium for Solana questions. Please use solana.stackexchange.com.

Ah really thank you i'm working on this for 72 hours now thank i think your work is very hard !

You should extract instructions from each quote response and pack them into one transaction. Check VersionedTransaction for example.

yes thanks i ask for help on jupiterdiscord (many scammer)
